# Sequelize unable to connect to SQL Server through network

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, connection-string

My setup is the following:

I have a Virtual Machine running all of my Database processes, let's call it DB-VM.

I'm currently developing at my own workstation (completely detached from DB-VM, except that we are under the same network.

I've created a valid connection string, validated by another database connection service throughout IIS and through a Data Link Properties file (.udl) and the connection.

[image: Connection String validation]

This connection is described by the connection string as:
`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=DB-VM\MY_DATABASE`.

I tried to insert it into my Sequelize configuration as following:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectModulePath: 'sequelize-msnodesqlv8',

    dialectOptions: {
        connectionString: 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=DB-VM\MY_DATABASE',
        trustedConnection: true,
    }
});
```

And then proceeded to try and authenticate through:

```
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection stablished successfully!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And this the error is as follows:
[image: Error description]

Notice: The database uses dynamic ports, therefore I can't specify the port through the `port` property.
Notice 2: The Named Pipes are disabled on my database settings, and I'm not sure if I will be able to enabled it.
Notice 3: The database is already setup to allow remote connections (it is currently used through a Webpage and works fine!

Comment: The connection string doesn't look right in the context of a node app. If you have a VM, you should specify host/port using "Server=". Named pipes are only for local communications. see https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/wiki#connecting

Comment: @battlmonstr, thank you for your input!
This connection string is what I use for an IIS / .NET connection to the database, I didn't know there was a difference between connection strings from Node and oher applications.

But since my database runs on dynamic ports, how could I specify a port when it constantly changes?

Comment: I would try to find a way to set a fixed constant port, or to be able to pass it as a config option to the scripts that start your VM, and then use the same config option for building the node app.

Comment: @battlmonstr, the way it was previously implemented was using an alias that would represent the database instance (I can use this alias to stablish a connection through the SSMS. Can't I still use that approach, because using a constant port is kind of a no-go as of now.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this line](https://github.com/ratanakvlun/sequelize-msnodesqlv8/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L72) the sequelize-msnodesqlv8 library expects "Driver" to be a part of the connection string, otherwise it tries to guess. Besides that, all the examples of connection strings [here1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8) and [here2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8) are using either `Server=myServerName\theInstanceName` or just `Server=myServerName`. Instead of the `Data Source=...`.

So step 1 is to fix you connection string. You could try one of the [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8#example-using-a-connection-string-directly-with-sequelize-pooling) like:

```
dialectOptions: {
    connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=DB-VM;Database=MY_DATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
},
```

After that if you get a new error, please update the question.

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to debug this? For example by adding a print statement into the code and see what is printed? I would try printing config properties in the code around [here](https://github.com/ratanakvlun/sequelize-msnodesqlv8/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L72)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

For some reason he's not detecting my configs. Here's the debug you requested: http://prntscr.com/n0o8w6

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a default empty config. You should be able to trace it upwards the stack, and see where it comes from, and particularly why "config.connectionString" comes as undefined.